# File Columns to Dictionary

Tags: python

Hello I have a file comprising 4 columns,

```
a  1  45  test
b  2  42  test
c  3  64  test
```

I wish to read this file to a dictionary such that column 3 is the key and column 1 is the value, i.e.,

```python
d = {45:'a', 42:'b', 64:'c'}
```

Comment: Did you try something on your own?

Comment: I have tried various approaches retrieved from here but without luck. I am a beginner in python. Thanks

Comment: It seems that the following solves my problem


dictVars = {}
for columns in ( raw.strip().split() for raw in file2 ):
        dictVars[columns[0]]=columns[2]

print dictVars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
>>> 
>>> d = dict()
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        val, foo, key, bar = line.split()
        d[key] = val


>>> d
{'64': 'c', '45': 'a', '42': 'b'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to parse the file. Change the delimiter parameter to whatever is the delimiter in your input file. I have assumed it to be tabs.

```
import csv
d = {}
with open('your-input-file', 'r') as input_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csv_reader:
        d[row[2]] = row[0]
input_file.close()
```

Comment: d[row[1]] = row[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Do a `print row` inside the for loop before assigning to the dictionary and check if it returns a list as `['a', '1', '45', 'test']`